# Properly round the corners of an element

Tags: css, grid

When I use border-radius to round the corners of an div its corners misbehave and look plain weird. The result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk9c5.png)

How can I get properly rounded the corners?

Comment: Tried to reproduce in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mb34z525/3/ , I guess just look which div you are trying to round

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was trivial, I was passing a value in % instead of px.

```css
div {
height: 50px;
width: 100px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.pixels {
border-radius: 15%;
background: firebrick;
}

.percentages {
border-radius: 15px;
background: seagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="pixels"></div>
<div class="percentages"></div>
```

Passing a value in % to border-radius made the button look elliptical instead of making the corners smoother.